# How to identify and save anonymous user choices in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a quiz app for students. Right now students have to first resister on the platform then they choose course and relevant quizzes appear before them. 
But what I want is : Students don't have to register first. They can choose course and then take one quiz then I will prompt them for a registration. What I want; when they register I can save data such as their course to a anonymous user (which they chose before registration) and link that to the account that will be created after they register.
So how I can I know what course did they choose before registration and how to link it to the user after they register?
Preferably through django rest framework as we an android app.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 'fake' user based on the session key.  Something like

```
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        #create anonymous user
        self.request.session.save()
        username = str(self.request.session.session_key) + '@dummy.com'
        try:
            user = MyUser.objects.create_user(username, is_fake=True)
        except:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(email=username)
        login(self.request, user)
```

Then if you have a username of this format you know they're not a real user and offer the normal options around login etc.